# Array push is not working inside of toArray function use mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I was try to loop through all documents that inside of collections, and store in a global var, but it looks like the push() is not working and return empty array [] inside of toArray(),
any suggestion?

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

var data = [];

const collections = mongo.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
    console.log('connection success');

    db.db().listCollections().toArray((err, colls) => {
        var collsPrinted = 0;
        colls.forEach(element => {
            db.db().collection(element.name).find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1).toArray((err, doc) => {

                data.push(doc);
                if (++collsPrinted == colls.length) db.close(); 
            });
        });        
    });
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log(data)` is being called before `data` is being populated.  Move your `console.log(data)` into your `if` block, like:

```
if (++collsPrinted == colls.length) {
     db.close();
     console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Most probably this can be the issue. Try to use async methods